# SET inside IF in MYSQL(?)

Tags: mysql

I'm new in MYSQL and I'm trying to do this:

```
UPDATE team
SET member1 = IF(member1=0, 001, SET member2 = IF(member2=0, 001, member2)) WHERE ID = ?;
```

This is not working, explain:
Each "member" has a different number (001, 002, 003...), I want to put the member "001" in the table "member1" but if this is ocupated (it has a value different of 0) set the member "001" in the table "member2" (a diferent table) but I think is not possible to put a SET inside of an IF. The id doesn't matters.

Thanks for attention ^^

Answer (score 1):

No you can't join `SET` statements like this. It'll have to be worked around:

```
UPDATE `team`
SET 
    `member2` = CASE WHEN `member1` = 0 AND `member2` = 0 THEN '001' ELSE `member2` END,
    `member1` = CASE WHEN `member1` = 0 THEN '001' ELSE `member1` END
WHERE 
    `id` = ?
/* optional filter: considering adding it if it does not bother the performance: */
AND (`member1` != 0 OR `member2` != 0)
;
```

*Notes:*

- I used backticks around table and column names, <s>I recommend you do so</s>*
- I used `CASE/WHEN` instead of `IF`, because `IF` is not ansi sql (it is specific to mysql)
- You could also do two queries instead of one. That would allow you to use a filter in the where clause, so you don't have to update the column when it's not required.

*as pointed out by Bohemian, they are not ansi. I like to use them for the structural and visual help they provide.

Comment: I recommend *not* using backticks, because they too are non ansi and because they introduce code noise

Comment: I changed in your code
 `member2` = CASE WHEN `member1` = 0 AND `member2` != 0 THEN '001' ELSE `member2` END,
 and its working perfectly! Thank you very much bro!